# PHP / Kohana: Protecting search query

Tags: php, kohana

I want to allow users to perform a search without restriction of any character what so ever.

Is it enough to "add slashes" and `/` or `mysql_escape_chars` in order to protect the DB from attacks?

What else would you suggest?

Thank you very much.

P.s. URI routing -> `www.example.com/search/category/query` where `query` is the term to be searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, such a protection is good enough (pretty much the same if you would insert data from a textarea ie.), but i would use mysql_real_escape_string instead. And don't forget to add 's around the search string in your mysql query (`... WHERE somecolumn LIKE 'query'` instead of `... WHERE somecolumn LIKE query`, same goes for `FULLTEXT` searches)

And please make sure to url_encode or base64_encode the query in the url query parameter

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick and insightful response.

Comment: you're very welcome :) one more addition: if you don't necessarily want your users to be able to save search url's think of using a POST request (this will make your url's cleaner, and will make Google a little bit happier ;))

Comment: Thank you, again. But I think I need a get request because this is a private knowledge base I am working on. But why would it make google happier? Also, do you mean that when somebody performs the query, I shall re-shape the URL for the results page with url_encode? Could you clarify please?

Thank you.

Comment: in SEO's perspective clean, short and descriptive URL's will give you some points. Eg. http://www.yoursite.com/buy-t-shirts/ will more likely end up high on Google than http://www.yoursite.com/pagex/pagey/morestuff/t-shirts/. Imagine what will happen if your url's are appended by the most random search terms. But as it's private it won't end up in Google anyway, so it doesn't matter. However this does not prevent you from using POST requests (I assume you're troubled with authentication?)

Answer (score 2):

The recommended solution, if passing queries straight through, is to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on the parameters – though this does require you to open a database connection first. This is important to avoid escapes mid-character using certain encodings by taking the character encoding of the database into account when escaping. Furthermore, `mysql_escape_string` is deprecated.

However, if possible, it is recommended that you instead use the [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) feature of the mysqli library; this enables you to pass query parameters as arguments to the PHP methods, thus *almost guaranteeing* you won't mess up, while removing the need to perform escaping.

Assuming you are using Kohana's built-in database tools, you can also use [its prepared statement support or query builder](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/query), which also supports prepared queries, and does not require escaping either.

Answer (score 2):

Use Kohana `ORM` / `Query Builder` - they will protect you against SQL injection. The only case when you need to watch out is when you use `DB::expr`, which doesn't escape your variables. Read more in [official docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/database/query/builder).

Answer (score -2):

the question makes not much sense to me.

1. Why search is only your concern? Dynamical SQL query taking parameters is the cornerstone of every our application. There should be a general purpose rule (or set of rules) covering every single case of dynamical SQL, not just one.
2. Kohana certainly have it's own tools to operate SQL. Why use raw "add slashes" / mysql_escape_chars instead?
3. www.example.com/search/category/query will require unnecessary redirect. Why not to use regular `/search?cat=category&q=query`? Google doesn't seem to think it's a shame to use such urls for the search - why should you?